# Seg fault in a producer consumer program

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, posix

I was learning concurrent programming by implementing producer consumer problem. The code just has one producer and one consumer. The consumer thread sit in a while loop blocked on an empty semaphore. The code generates segfault 11 which I am not able debug. I tried removing the while loop in the consumer thread, after which I don't see the segfault why is that ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <queue>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;

queue<int> buff;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sem_t empty;

void producer(int i){

   pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
   buff.push(i);
   sem_post(&empty);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

}

void* produce_data(void* arg){
    for(int i = 5 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        producer(i);
    }

   return NULL;
}

void* consumer(void* arg){

    while(1){
        sem_wait(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        int temp = buff.front();
        cout << temp <<" " ;
        buff.pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
     }

    return 0;
}

int main () {
   pthread_t prod;
   sem_init(&empty, 0, 0);
   pthread_create(&prod, NULL, produce_data , NULL);

   pthread_t consum2;

   pthread_create(&consum2, NULL,consumer , NULL);

   pthread_join(prod,NULL);

   pthread_join(consum2,NULL);


   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what, precisely, makes you "unable to debug" this simple program?

Comment: move `sem_post` outside the mutex.

Comment: I tried to printout some stuff but didn't help . Like in the consumer what I am doing is just poping the queue  and then sleep on the semaphore , I am not sure how can I access illegal memory here

Comment: @stark didn't help putting sem_post outside

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Adding code to flush `cout` results in the expected output followed by a hang because one thread is in `pthread_join` and the other is in an endless `while` loop.

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors?   Maybe start with the sem functions; like if (sem_init(&empty, 0, 0)) { perror("sem_init"); }; then move on to the mutex ones, see if anything pops out.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that helped a bit now I can see 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0  .... lots of zeros and then seg fault 11

Comment: @DavidSchwartz flush the cout seems to work ! What's the explanation for this ?

Comment: @PunitSalian I am unable to produce a segfault from your code regardless of how I try. I don't see why your code would fault unless the code posted is not the correct code. Are you 100% sure the exact code you shared in your question produces a segfault?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes david it's the exact same code. I am using the g++ on Mac and still get the segfault ,but  tried executing the same in an online compiler,I get the expected output with the flush on cout .My MAC g++ version                                                                                                   
 Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: @PunitSalian Does your compiler require `-pthread` or something similar to compile code that uses the pthreads standard?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Nope nothing as such just compile :g++ prod_consumer.cc -o prod.o  no linking of the pthread

Answer (score 0):

Sem_init() is deprecated in macos.  Compiling your program should have shown this.  Also, if you checked the return values, you would know that sem_init(), sem_post(), sem_wait() were all failing.   For whatever reason, somewhere around 1023 pops from your queue, and it SEGV's.